# Could not execute node.js on ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to create an AWS Cloud9 environment by using an existing EC2 instance, however it fails with the error seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

What I have tried so far :

As suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28933310/could-not-execute-node-js-cloud9), I tried installing the nodejs-legacy but ran into the error below :

[image]

Comment: If this is a brand new machine did you run apt update first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by installing ***nodejs-legancy*** using the following commands below :

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs nodejs-legacy
```